# How to refine sampling of points via averaging?

Tags: accuracy, sampling, generative-models

I am working with a generative model which is generating points that are less accurate than I would like. I have strong reason to believe the errors should average out along a particular axis (to give an oversimplified example, say the desired sample is a plane of points, and the actual sample the model outputs is a rectangular prism of points encasing that plane with some thickness, which would represent the level of inaccuracy). I would like to add a post-processing step to my model to improve the accuracy. Is there a way I can use this property, that the generated points seem to surround/encase the desired result, to improve the accuracy of my sampling, specifically in a way that is scalable/generalizable to other problems/geometries? In other words, if presented with a set of points that define a geometric shape, how might one alter/use those points to obtain only values which represent the 'inner core' of that shape, without necessarily knowing the nature of the desired result?